# how to add a route or direction to cluster in google map api-3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, sorting, google-maps-api-3

Marker cluster in google maps is used to manage many markers ,
can i use cluster find direction for markers near by each others?

i am trying to create  independent paths "direction " for each cluster
 take a look at this photo http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2h2gu2d&s=9

i want group 1 "cluster" to have its own directions 
group 2 "cluster"  to have its own directions and so on for 3 and 4 .

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(gm_map, clusterMarkers, options_markerclusterer);

google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
    $('#toggle-photolist').fadeIn();
    $('#close-overlay').fadeIn();
    $('#view-multiblephotos').show();
    $('#view-singlephoto').hide();

    var markers = cluster.getMarkers();

    var array = [];
    var num = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

        num++;
        array.push(markers[i].getTitle() + '<br>');
    }

    $('#count-photos').text(num);
    $('#list-photos').show().html(array.join(''));

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/RGS5b/

Comment: What do you mean by "group 1 cluster to have its own directions"? For it to act as a marker to go to group 2? Or for group 1 to have directions with each other (which I'm presuming is not the case)?

Comment: i meant the markers near to each other should have their own path " direction" "grouped " as if you are searching one by one route but in Single map  ,take a look at the photo .@adjuremods

Comment: Yeah I looked into it. Still a bit confused about the question. From how I understand it, all markers in group 1 will have directions/routes with each other. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: yes this what i meant.

Comment: Can't you just get the markers and loop them to get directions from each other? Though that will be hard if there's a lot of markers in a cluster due to the number of combinations the group will have.